# A.I. for card game similar to 3-5-8 (also known as Sergeant Major)

Tags: artificial-intelligence, game-engine, expert-system

I have to implement card game similar to 3-5-8, but I have problem to select proper way for A.I. implementation. Is it possible game A.I. to be created with package like OpenRules business decision management system? I have looked at Drools also, but it seems too complicated.

Are expert systems, in general, proper for such A.I. development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on whether your solution employs heuristics or algorithms (or possibly a combination of both). For example, in chess you have complete knowledge of the game state and can plan turns in advance so a minimax algorithm allows you to find an "optimal" solution for any given search depth. A heuristic "good enough" solution can be used in situations where an optimal solution is not possible or difficult to determine (because the game state is not fully known, there is chance involved, or the number of player choices is too large to consider). For example, you can easily create basic heuristics for what to do in a blackjack or poker game based on the cards in your hand and the cards showing in other player hands. These simple heuristics could then be later expanded to include additional heuristics.

Here's a simple set of rules (i.e. heuristics) for winning a trick in a card game:

```
Rule FirstPlayHighTrump
   When
      You're playing the first card and
      You have trump cards
   Then
      Play the highest trump card in your hand

Rule FirstPlayHighCard    
   When
      You're playing the first card and
      You don't have trump cards
   Then
      Play the highest card in your hand

Rule PlayHighCard
   When
      You're not playing the first or last card and
      You have a card to win the trick
   Then
      Play the highest card in your hand that will win the trick

Rule PlayLowCard
   When
     You don't have a card to win the trick
   Then
      Play the lowest card in your hand 

Rule LastPlayLowestCardToWin
   When
      You're playing the last card and
      You have a card to win the trick
   Then
      Play the lowest card in your hand that will win the trick
```

These rules/heuristics are better than picking cards that follow suit at random, but since they don't involve planning for winning the next trick, they can be improved.

Comment: If-else chain is what I would like to escape. The game 3-5-8 has a lot covered information (the player does not know the cards of his/her two opponents). 

I am wondering is it possible if-else change to be replaced with some kind of rule engine. The biggest advantage will be that rules will be outside of the source code. Rules can be changed without need to recompile the game.

Comment: What about artificial neural networks? Is it posible ANN to be used in the A.I. of this game?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31844298/how-to-train-an-ann-to-play-a-card-game